# how this code works i didn't undestand clearly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

```js
const show1 = function(x, y = () => {x = 2; return x;}) {
    console.log(y());
    console.log(x);
};
```

how does this code work?

what does  this thing do ?
 function(x, y = () => {x = 2; return x;}) {

its just for improve coding knowledge and nothing else :)

Comment: If `y` isn't passed or is undefined, it sets it to a function that reassigns and returns the first parameter passed

Comment: its just default parameter value

Comment: can you show the linkdude

Comment: Actually, that's not quite right, the default parameter's scope is pretty strange, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58219009/if-re-declaration-with-var-will-have-effect-on-existed-variable