# If re-declaration with var will have effect on existed variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
const show1 = function(x, y = () => {x = 2; return x;}) {
    let x = 3;
    console.log(y());
    console.log(x);
};
show1();
```

```js
const show2 = function(x, y = () => {x = 2; return x;}) {
    x = 3;
    console.log(y());
    console.log(x);
};
show2();
```

```js
const show3 = function(x, y = () => {x = 2; return x;}) {
    var x = 3;
    console.log(y());
    console.log(x);
};
show3();
```

#### output

```
show1: Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'x' has already been decalred;
show2: 2 2
show3: 2 3
```

#### Question

I was informed that there is a temporary dead zone where parameter variables are declared and initialized. See https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_variables.html#sec_parameters-as-variables. So there are two scopes here, one is the parameter scope and the other is function scope.

1. From the error in show1, I thought that there is a `x` variable already declared in this function.
2. According to [Redeclaring a javascript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888506/redeclaring-a-javascript-variable). The re-declaration won't do anything to `x`(with `var`). Why the results of `show2` and `show3` are different.

I posted the same question here [If the variables are already declared at the beginning of function execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58217304/if-the-variables-are-already-declared-at-the-beginning-of-function-execution) which was masked as duplicate. But I couldn't find anything useful for my doubt.

Comment: *According to Redeclaring a javascript variable. The re-declaration won't do anything to x* See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58219129/ , that isn't correct when using modern syntax (`const` and `let`), which none of the other answers there have mentioned; if a variable name is declared with `const` or `let`, it must not be initialized elsewhere (such as in the parameter list, or with `var` elsewhere in the block)

Comment: @CertainPerformance That's the case in show1. What about the difference in show2 and show3?

Comment: @BAKE ZQ see my answer

Answer (score 4):

`show1` throws an error because variables declared with `let` or `const` [cannot have any other variables with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58219129/) initialized in that block (whether in an argument list or with `const` / `let` / `var`).

---

Variables referenced by default parameters have odd scoping rules. Every argument essentially creates another block that that argument name can be defined in. So

```
const show3 = function(x, y = () => { x = 2; return x; }) {
```

is *somewhat* like (forgive the psuedo-code):

```
const show3 = < function >{
  let x = firstArg;
  {
    let y = secondArg === undefined ? () => { x = 2; return x; } : secondArg;
    {
      // function body
```

When you simply *assign* to a variable name in the argument list, that argument will be overwritten. But when you use syntax to *initialize* a new variable (with `var`), you've created *another* binding for that variable name, which is only visible inside the function body:

```
const show3 = {
  let x = firstArg;
  {
    let y = secondArg === undefined ? () => { x = 2; return x; }
    // the x referenced in the above line references the outer x, the first argument
    {
      // function body

      // since "var x" is declared here, any references to "x" in this block
      // will only reference the inner x
      // but not the outer x
      var x = /* something */
```

So, your `show2` is reassigning the parameter named `x` to 3 in the first line of the function body. In contrast, `show3` is creating a *new* variable binding with the same name of `x`, while the `y` function's reference to `x` is referencing the argument `x`, which is different.

Comment: If you mean that there is no `x` declared in this function. I am referring the argument `x` in the parameter scope?

Comment: Pretty much - the scope of a variable in the parameter list is (very slightly) different from the scope of a variable declared in the function body, though it'll rarely have a noticeable effect on code.

Comment: What if there are no default values for parameters. If this parameter scope still exists? And with the assumption that these two scopes are different, why I cant' use `let` or `const` here? (Since they are in different blocks. I can write codes like `{let a = 0; { let a = 0}}`)

Comment: If there aren't any default parameters, then if there's an argument `x`, `var x =` will be indistinguishable from `x =`, because there are no scopes other than the function body which can reference the *argument alone*. I'm sure the specification describes the precise behavior, but whatever it is, it's not observable

Comment: For whatever reason, it just happened to be decided that variables declared with `let` and `const` shadowing an argument variable name would throw an error (probably because it results in confusing semantics), even though it'd *look* like such a thing would be OK from the psuedo-code above

Answer (score 1):

`Why the results of show2 and show3 are different.`

let's evaluate your code by this way

```
const show2 = function(x, y = () => {x.value = 2; return x;}) {
    x = {name: "from argument", value: 3};
    console.log(y());//{name: "from argument", value: 2}
    console.log(x);//{name: "from argument", value: 2}
};
show2();

const show3 = function(x, y = () => {if(!x){x = {name:"from function", value: -1}}x.value = 2; return x;}) {
    var x = {name: "from var", value: 3};
    console.log(y());//{name: "from function", value: 2}
    console.log(x);//{name: "from var", value: 3}
};
show3();

const show4 = function(x, y = () => {if(!x){x = {name:"from function", value: -1}}x.value = 2; return x;}) {
    var x = {name: "from var", value: 3};
    console.log(y());//{name: "from outside", value: 2}
    console.log(x);//{name: "from var", value: 3}
};
show4({name:"from outside", value: -1})
```

Comment: Thx. Then I was wrong. There is only a `x` variable in arguments. Right? The `x` in in show2 is actually the result of looking variable in argument list(or scope)

Comment: For case 2 look like so. As I understand, there is 3 scopes `{global{function{scope of function arguments {scope of function body}}}}`

Comment: It makes sense now. But how to explain the peculiar behavior of `let`. Or it's because `It happend to be` said by @Certainperformance

Comment: Yes, should be. I can't explain it now, currently your question stops work of all our department